# How to make the APFS container bigger, when Disk Utility always create a new, empty APFS container?

Tags: macos, mac, apfs

I found blogs to shrink an APFS container, but not to grow it.  There is one Stack Overflow post about growing it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47704458/how-do-you-increase-the-size-of-an-apfs-volume

However, for me, I had a 500GB SSD drive, and 450GB was HFS+, 50GB was APFS.  I was able to shrink down the HFS+ partition to about 420GB.  However, Disk Utility immediately created another AFPS container which is about 30GB, and it cannot be used with the original `disk2`, which I assume is both the APFS container and volume which is 50GB.

When I do

```
diskutil apfs resizeContainer disk2 0
```

or

```
diskutil apfs resizeContainer disk2 76g
```

(The `76g` should mean 76GB, and `0` should mean "maximum")

it always says the size cannot be the same or there is not enough space (`Error: -69519`).  When I use Disk Utility to delete the empty APFS container, it would immediately create a new one.

So to hack it, I found out that container is `disk3` and I used

```
diskutil apfs resizeContainer disk3 2g
```

and it succeeded, and the Partition pie chart in Disk Utility now shows "Free Space", but then the two commands up above both still say the same thing.  What can be done to grow it from 50GB to about 78GB or 76GB?

Comment: Partitions can generally only grow/shrink at the *end* of the partition, not at its beginning. You have free space before the beginning of your APFS partition rather than at its end, so it cannot be added. At least not directly...

Comment: @GordonDavisson has it always been like that, even for HFS+ ? You know that because it is `disk2` and `disk1` should be the 450GB HFS+ ? I guess there is no way to create an empty container can let it contain `disk2` and that "before" volume

Comment: It's always been like that. You might be able to create a new 30GB APFS container, clone the current 50GB one's contents into it (provided there's less than 30GB actually in it), delete the 50GB container, then expand the 30GB out to 80... but I'd recommend making sure you have a good backup of everything (including the HFS+ volume's contents) before doing it. I'm seeing too many reports of corrupted volumes recently to trust the disk tools.

Comment: @GordonDavisson that APFS and Catalina was what I installed back in 2019 and I haven't used it more than a few hours...  so it seems I can also do it: boot up to Mavericks or Sierra (whatever on that 410GB HFS+ drive).  Now just wipe the other partition out, making it all free space.  Now perhaps remove or move some file and create more free space, make it 130GB free space and resize the partition and create a brand new partition on it that is 120GB, and then install Catalina on it... or if I don't want to resize it one more time, simply create a partition with about 90GB on it.

Comment: @GordonDavisson and actually, isn't this kind of problem the same as what Partition Magic back in the year 2000 solved? I can't believe 20 years later, it is still the simple problem that isn't solved (on a Mac). And what's  more, since we have SSD, supposedly isn't it much more flexible? For example, it virtually can let user merge two partitions together and just have a mapping table that says "cluster XYZ" is really cluster ABC on the SSD, and access is super fast. Grow at the tail but can't grow at the beginning seems so stone age

Comment: Apple attempted to solve the problem you describe by creating APFS. Under APFS, a container can hold many volumes. You can add or remove volumes without having to repartition. The default configuration would be to have a small EFI partition at the beginning of the drive, followed by a APFS container partition. Under this configuration, there would be no need to move the beginning of the APFS partition. One may wish to move the end of the APFS partition to accommodate the addition or removal of other partition types.

Comment: While have more than one APFS container partition per disk is possible, this can create the problem of needing to move the beginning of the second APFS partition. There are third party tools that can move an entire partition, however I would not recommend using such a tool without first backup up the data. Once the data is backed up, you could attempt a move. However, you could also delete the partition, create a partition in new location, then restore from backup. This avoids the need for a third party tool.